# css gradient background button

Tags: html, css, button, input, gradient

I would create a button like this (GetStarted button) in this page:
http://www.behance.net/signup/

I don't know how create the blue background gradient button. I don't understand what are the css property to use.

Who can help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could try some simple css button generators: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/ or http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/. They are at least a good place to start if you're unclear on most of the css.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, they used this in default state:

```
background: #0079FF;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0096FF), to(#005DFF));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0096FF), to(#005DFF));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #0096FF, #005DFF);
```

For hover they have other colors of course. Just change the color for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KJN2V/1/

Just add the .button class to any element you wish

Answer (score 0):

```
I used this for creating a gradient button.   
<style>
        .my-gradient-btn {
            border-radius: 40px;
            opacity: 0.5;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
        }
       </style>
```

[image]